# Jython OutOfMemoryError with Pydev, Eclipse Neon and JDK 8

Tags: python, eclipse, jython, pydev

I'm migrating to Eclipse Neon using JDK 8, and I installed PyDev on it.

When I try to launch a PyDev console with Jython as the interpret, the interpreter throws an OutOfMemoryError (java heap space). [image]

My current eclipse settings are as follows:

[image]

I've tried other vm arguments (-XX:+UseG1GC for example), but the error is always the same. The moment I hit an indentation or a flow control statement, things go pear-shaped.

Any ideas? This issue does not occur at all when I launch a PyDev console with native Python.

Comment: You could try giving more heap (-Xmx4096m for example). If that doesn't help it's probably a bug. You could either debug the issue or try upgrading components.

Comment: I'm using the latest components, and adding 4GB for max heap for eclipse seems rather excessive. I don't think I've ever run it with more than 1GB for either Java or C++ development (and I didn't have this problem under Indigo and JDK 7.) I am going to have to assume it is a bug and just rely on native Python for the repl. Thanks.

Comment: Adding 4GB as the max didn't help. Same problem. The error `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded` suggests the GC is spending too much time when Jython is trying to parse. Definitely a bug since this behavior is new.